# interrobang symbol in jadetex

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I need to use an interrobang  ‽  in a document that ultimately goes through jadetex, but that gives me an error:

Warning: Unknown character 8253, at 9956

I *think* this is because that character isn't present in the Times-New-Roman font file jadetex is looking at.  My thought is to use metafont to add that character, so my question is, how do I identify the right .mf file?

Of course, if there's any less intrusive way to get that character, I'd be delighted to hear about it.

Thanks.

Comment: why metafont? It may be hard to find a times-like metafont, and you would end up with a bitmap in the pdf, you could use a small pdf made from the system times-roman or simplest just construct an over-printed !? with negative space tuned to your font

Comment: like latex's inputenc warning (which took the code from here) the warning  is not related to whether the font has the character,but rather just saying there is no mapping of U+203D to anything, so first map it to say `\interrobang` then define that as  `!\!?` or whatever

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The outer layer of all this is docbook2pdf, so the first thing I tried was using fontforge to add an interrobang the Times New Roman font.  Didn't work, but it could be just because I didn't stick the modified tnr ttf in the right place and it started to look like jadetex was mapping tnr to cmr, so I thought metafont might be the way to go.  I'm probably wrong.

I'll try the \interrobang ==> !\!? thing; much appreciated.

Comment: it would help if you posted a small jade generated jadetex file that gives that error. preferably with just text `abc‽` I wrote large parts of the system but getting rusty, I couldn't acually generate exactly the error you show

Comment: is... ? :-) Don't add code in comments it doesn't really work, add a complete document that reproduces the error (not a fragment) to your question in  code block

Comment: The bit that causes the problem is \Character{8253} where 8253 is the decimal unicode for interrobang.  This results in pdfjadetex "Warning: Unknown character 8253, at 9949" and "<8253>" being inserted into the resultant pdf.  I'm getting around this by using just plain "?!" and then using sed to replace the "?!" with "?\kern-.4em !" in the tex, where .4em is my eyeball estimate of what makes the bang and the qmark line up.  Not ideal, but it works.  Obviously, jadetex can handle some two-byte unicode characters--I see a \Character{8220} that works fine--but not interrobang.

Comment: Sorry, the bit from yesterday, "The bit that causes the problem is – 
Chris Moller 16 hours ago," was an unfinished entry.